# Saving a files in React-Native using react-native-fs library

Tags: javascript, react-native

After saving a file using `react-native-fs` where does that file go?

It's not explained in the documentation or I couldn't find and it's hard to figure.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you create a file you have to specify a directory where to store the file. In the example below the `path` variable shows where the file will be written to.

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// create a path you want to write to
// :warning: on iOS, you cannot write into `RNFS.MainBundlePath`,
// but `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` exists on both platforms and is writable
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';

// write the file
RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

There are several places you can store your files

The following [directories](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants) are available:

> - `MainBundlePath` (String) The absolute path to the main bundle directory
>     (not available on Android)
> - `CachesDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the caches directory
> - `ExternalCachesDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the external caches directory (android only)
> - `DocumentDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the document directory
> - `TemporaryDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the temporary directory (falls back to Caching-Directory on Android)
> - `LibraryDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the NSLibraryDirectory (iOS only)
> - `ExternalDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the external files, shared directory (android only)
> - `ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` (String) The absolute path to the external storage, shared directory (android only)

So all you have to do is choose the directory.  Note these directories are on the device.

### Seeing the files on the device

#### iOS Simulator

If you want to find the file on your simulator on iOS all you need to do is console.log the path, which should look something like this

```
/Users/work/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2F8BEC88-BF42-4D6B-81D4-A77E6ED8CB00/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC16D2A6-55A2-475C-8173-B650A4E40CF1/Documents/
```

Open `Finder`, select `Go to folder`

[image]

And then paste in the path and that will open the folder where the file is.

[image]

#### Android Emulator

If you console.log the path for the file you should get something like this

```
/data/user/0/com.awesomeapp/files/
```

You have to run the app from Android Studio, then you need to access the `Device View Explorer`. You do that by going to `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Device File Explorer`

[image]

That should then open a windows that looks like this, where you can then browse to the file path that you were given above.

[image]

Comment: When I installed my app on my physical device with this code. In console I see File Written, but where is the file on my physical device? How I can choose the directory?

Comment: Thank you , your comment was a big help.                                                                 Do you by any chance know how to make it so when we click on a button 'export file' it shows a directory to save that file.                                                                                           is it possible with this library ? Otherwise please recommend one.

Comment: Hi @Forad, were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @Andrew I have a .pdf file. I need to show a download button in UI and need to download the document. Not need to view or anything just show the button and download? How can I achieve this?

Comment: @sejn I would suggest writing up the relevant parts into a new question so that you can clearly express everything that you need to do, make sure you include all the code that is relevant, and what you have tried so far. Make sure you include a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The comments on SO do not really allow a detailed discussion to take place. For one, code does not format nicely here; and secondly, you are limited to 600 characters, so it makes it hard to express oneself fully.

Comment: I have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538972/clarification-can-i-able-to-store-doc-files-in-my-react-native-app-and-download. I not written any code for this. I need to implement then only, I don't have any idea how to implement this in react-native

Comment: That's great that you have asked a question, hopefully someone will answer it. I would suggest making sure that you read the article on [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and update your question accordingly, so that your question stands more chance of being answered.

Comment: @Forad did you find where is the file on physical device, I can't seem to find it and it has been more than 2 hours. is in inaccessible? or what?

Answer (score 0):

i got another way using **RNFS** from **'react-native-fs'**
where im storing Pdf file to **FireBase** Storage.

```
Firstly im finding the Absolute Path of selected PDF
secondly copying that file to locally,then getting exact path of copied Tempfile and uploading that,
Once uploading done to Cloud i deleted Locally saved temp Pdf file  

Hence Problem solved
```

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';


 try {
      let Filename = fileName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
      const extension = fileName.split('.').slice(1).join('.');
      const NameWithoutExtension = Filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
      Filename = Filename + Date.now() + '.' + extension;
      // console.log('extension:', Filename);

      setLoader(true);
      RNFS.copyFile(file, RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/tempFile.' + extension)
        .then(copyResponce => {
          console.log('copyResponce:', copyResponce);
          RNFS.exists(RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/tempFile.' + extension)
            .then(isexist => {
              console.log('isexist:', isexist);

              const StorageRef = storage().ref(`ResumeData/${Filename}`);
              StorageRef.putFile(
                RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/tempFile.' + extension,
              )
                .then(async res => {
                  const url = await StorageRef.getDownloadURL();
                  console.log('fileuploaded:', url);
                  console.log('res:', res);
                  //adding data to firebase cloud
                  await firestore()
                    .collection(DB_Name.all_resource)
                    .add({
                      Name: Name,
                      Experience: Experience,
                      Technology: service,
                      Contact: Phone,
                      Resume: url,
                      senderId: uid,
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log('Resource Post Success!');
                      navigation.goBack();
                      setLoader(false);
                      setExperience(null);
                      setName(null);
                    });
                  // Removing Temp stored file
                  RNFS.unlink(
                    RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/tempFile.' + extension,
                  )
                    .then(del => {
                      setLoader(false);
                      console.log('delete Tempfile Success!', del);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      setLoader(false);
                      console.log('Error in Deleting Tempfile:', error);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  setLoader(false);
                  console.log('errorin uploading', error);
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              setLoader(false);
              console.log('notExist:', err);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error in Copy Responce:', error));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error In storing Pdf:', err);
    }
```